# Deserialize a nested json java with some operations

Tags: java, json

I am quite new to this, 
I have a `JSON` and i am using `Json`(org.json) library to deserialize that.

```
{
   "isSomething":false,
   "previous":0,
   "id":123456,
   "things":[
      {
         "a":3,
         "id":4
      },
      {
         "a":1,
         "id":5
      },
   ]
}
```

after deserialization, I want this to become an object like.

```
{
   "isSomething":false,
   "previous":0,
   "id":123456,
   "thingsCount":2,    //size of list
   "totalA":4,         // addition of all a's
   "listIds":[4,5]     // list of all the ids in things.
}
```

I have tried to do this like 
This is my class but i am getting an exception
This example was taken from somewhere else as a reference.

```
    @JsonProperty("isSomething")
    Boolean isSomething;
    @JsonProperty("previous")
    int previous;

    @JsonSetter(value = "things")
    public void thingsCount(List<JSONObject> things) {
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(things)) {
            this.thingsCount = things.size();
            this.totalA = 0;
            this.listIds = new ArrayList<>();
            for(JSONObject object : things) {
                this.totalA = this.totalA + object.getInt("a");
                this.listIds.add(object.getLong("id"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception -

> caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "a" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as
>   ignorable (0 known properties: ])

with no luck, is it possible to deserialize this the way i want it or i have to take another approach(like use the calculation after deserialization) , if not whats the right way to do it. 
Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think calculation after deserialization might be more suitable:

```java
public class SomeJson {
  boolean isSomething;
  int previous;
  long id;
  List<Thing> things;

  public EndResult getEndResult() {
    int totalA = things.stream().map(thing -> thing.a).sum();
    List<Long> listIds = things.stream().map(thing -> thing.id).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new EndResult(isSomething, previous, id, things.size(), totalA, listIds); 
  }
}

public class Thing {
  int a;
  int id;
}

public class EndResult {
  boolean isSomething;
  int previous;
  int id; 
  int thingsCount; 
  int totalA;
  List<Integer> listIds;
}
```

Then, if you use [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) you can simply do:

```java
String json = // YOUR JSON

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
SomeJson deserializedJson = objectMapper.readValue(json, SomeJson.class); 
EndResult endResult = someJson.getEndResult();
```